# Why "smashed avocado" rather than "mashed avocado"?

Tags: differences, australian-english, food

In the context of gastronomy, what is the difference, if any, between "smashed" and "mashed"? I'm familiar with "mashed" being used, such as in "mashed potato", but hadn't heard of "smashed" being used this way, until "smashed avocado" become a [buzzword](https://www.buzzfeed.com/markdistefano/sold-to-the-kid-eating-avo-toast) for young people spending too much money rather than saving up for a house:

> I have seen young people order **smashed avocado** with crumbled feta on
>   five-grain toasted bread at $22 a pop and more. I can afford to eat
>   this for lunch because I am middle-aged and have raised my family. But
>   how can young people afford to eat like this? Shouldn’t they be
>   economising by eating at home? How often are they eating out?
>   Twenty-two dollars several times a week could go towards a deposit on
>   a house.

Comment: Mashed avocado is made using a fork; smashed avocado is made using a hammer.

Comment: Maybe a cooking question... http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: While you are asking about word usage, given that this is specifically about differences in methods of preparing food, you might get answers which address the issue in more detail on [cooking.se].

Comment: It may also be a regional/dialectal thing, given the source is Australian.

Comment: As [Gallagher taught us](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErppAlOIGQE), if it's not sprayed on you and the walls, it's not smashed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that ***[smash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smash)*** and ***[mash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mash)*** suggests that avocado has been prepared in a different way,  for instance:

> "Mashed" potatoes are smoothly whipped with cream, butter, etc.
>   "Smashed" potatoes,  are more with pieces of chunk potato as well as smooth bits. There's still butter or whatever but again it's not smoothly incorporated.

The Free Dictionary

[image]

***[Smashed avocado](http://www.self.com/tools/drop10/2014/03/smashed-avocado-toast)*** From: (www.self.com)

[image]

***[Mashed avocado](https://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/custom_covers/216x146/228205974807184686_1350255382.jpg&imgrefurl=https://es.pinterest.com/ArcherJackie/&h=146&w=216&tbnid=H6huEw2zBPV5_M&tbnh=116&tbnw=172&usg=__CVrg_ys5XNXAWzSOqZwoeKmRLYs=&docid=j2ewjgPJKr8XnM)***                From: (www.gettyimages.co.nz)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's originally a mistake coming from someone who speaks English as a second language, as myself. It took me sometime to know the difference. I'm talking about half a century ago

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).